# ng-token-auth get logged in user

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, authentication, devise

I am trying to make an angular app. I am using rails with devise_token_auth in backend. I am trying to setup the angular app with ng-token-auth.
I have read up everything I can find online for past whole week but still couldn't figure out how to get the user currently signed in.
I understand that auth:login-success event returns a user object.
I understand there is validateUser method which validates if auth token is present and is valid, and it is run on page load.
How do I retrieve the user whose token is present in storage or cookie on page load or at any other time, kind of similar to current_user in rails.
There dosen't seem to be any such thing in built in ng-token-auth.
How do I accomplish this.
Is there any flaw in my approach or assumption ?
I am learning angular by building an app and am REALLY stuck at this point.

Comment: `Is there any flaw in my approach or assumption ?` what you tried??

Comment: This is my first time trying on this library...I assumed it would have some method for retriving the current user from the token stored in cookie or storage...Is this true ? if yes what is it and if no, what is the best/widespread way of doing this ? thanks @Arpit

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried storing the user object in ngStorage and then doing calls with the auth token for that user?

Comment: That would be possible..but I am interested to know if the library handles this itself somewhre that I am not aware of @Casualbot